# How to make client-client connection in js without node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to make simple game of Tic-Tac-Toe in JS.

I made almost everything. Now there is just one thing to do.

I would like to make it available to play online with someone.

I want to send data between two games via Internet.

Unfortunately my server does not support Node.JS.

Is there a way to make it happen without any server-side "socket".

I thought I could make it with `XMLHttpRequest()` for saving/loading data into/from server files and play like that, but I think it would require a lot of code and maybe for ttt it would be fast enough, but for more complicated games it would not be sufficient.

I know this is tough, but how did they do that before node.js?

Comment: NodeJS is just one of many server side programming-languages / frameworks you could choose from. Use one which your server can support (although...AFAIK Node runs on most platforms, so not sure what's stopping you installing it, unless you're referring to a shared hosting plan you have bought?). They will all support AJAX (i.e. XmlHttpRequest) and many support WebSocket connections (usually with a bit of configuration for the latter, admittedly). PHP and ASP.NET both definitely have websocket implementations, just for example. There is a standard for websockets which anyone can implement.

Comment: NodeJS is [not a hard requirement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications) for WebSockets.

Comment: Of course your other option is to move to a server environment which supports what you need...it's usually a good idea to scope out the support/environment requirements _before_ you set the server up.

Comment: Well. I checked and there is WebSocket support, just any way of configuration on my hosting plan is blocked, so there will be no configuration. I could just use XmlHttpRequest, but do I have to use files then, or can I connect two clients with each others just for the play w/o creating any files?

Comment: I know, this sucks, but my hosting plan is the cheapest possible. It was only setted up to keep my links/small files or to trasnfer files quickly from one pc to other when there is no usb-stick available. I just pay for more space so, its basically free, but without ads and with a bit more space than free account. Only thing I can configure is PHP version.

Comment: If you use HTTP -- which is what `XMLHttpRequest` and its more modern brethren like Fetch API use -- you, first of all, are using TCP protocol, which is stream and bandwidth oriented (as opposed to latency), and on top of that paying with latency again for HTTP -- where requests and responses may outweight your data payloads and have to be parsed even before you get to build your requests and parse your response bodies. Depending on the nature of your game, you might want to resort to WebSockets or WebRTC (if you must have P2P). Otherwise, HTTP may suffice.

Comment: @amn I don't think there will be a lot of data to send, really I just need to send 3 numbers each time a player makes a move. It should not overwhelm server. And I really would prefer P2P, I think, I will check out PeerJS. It looks like a solution.

Comment: "there is WebSocket support, just any way of configuration on my hosting plan is blocked, so there will be no configuration" ...if it's already supported, then you probably don't need to do much configuration. By configuration I meant installing websocket components and getting the socket connection working. if it's already supported by the hosting company then you shouldn't have too much issue.

Comment: And no you can't generally make two browsers talk to each other directly, you need a server in between. There is webRTC which is p2p but it's really intended for audio and video primarily. It might work for general data as well, but i'm not sure. And it still requires a server to co-ordinate the connections, unless people already know each other's IDs.

Comment: As far as I know WebRTC is decidedly peer-to-peer, after peer IDs are made known to all parties with the help of a signaling server. In fact, WebRTC is designed to try its hardest to communicate to peers directly, and only resort to TURN services if it's unable to communicate peer-to-peer. In practice, a lot of networks do not allow IP packets to travel freely from one arbitrary host to another, and some do only after STUN punches holes in the firewalls in between the hosts and causes intermediate routers to set up NAT tables.

Comment: Also, WebRTC is not just for audio/video, it's design goals are realtime communication between Web browsers, which obviously covers messaging and signaling as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a game like Tic-Tac-Toe where players take turns, latency definitely takes second seat to every other factor in communications. For this reason alone, communicating with just the HTTP protocol, typically by utilizing the [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/) class or the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), is a very reasonable approach which will save you a lot of programming effort.

Otherwise, when wanting one or several low-latency and/or [RTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_communication) channels (for hopefully a good reason), both [WebRTC](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/) and [WebSocket](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/#the-websocket-interface) are viable candidates.

WebRTC, for one, can absolutely do peer-to-peer, while WebSocket uses the client-server model. But even WebRTC requires a "signalling" service to exchange peer identifiers initially, before eventually switching to communicating between the peers directly. While peer identifiers are required to set up WebRTC communication, the API deliberately does not cover how peer identifiers are exchanged -- however you want to design your signalling service, is up to you. For all WebRTC cares, you can "POST" a peer ID to a HTTP server and retrieve it with the other peer's Web browser and vice-versa. WebRTC starts with already known peer IDs.

Otherwise, if configured to do so, WebRTC is able to utilize [STUN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN) and/or [TURN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traversal_Using_Relays_around_NAT) services to maintain peer-to-peer connection, on networks that otherwise prohibit straightforward IP routing between any two clients -- a necessary prerequisite of true peer-to-peer communication.

STUN/TURN services aren't required in all cases, but knowing average network conditions, without using either STUN or TURN or both, your application wouldn't be very reliable for any two clients separated by multiple arbitrary networks. Like in scenarios where both parties are separated by at least one firewall or a stubborn router that functions as one.

A TURN service would then transparently route WebRTC communication, working as a relay.

A STUN service punches holes in the firewalls between clients in such a way that peer-to-peer communication is possible afterwards. Meaning that in contrast with a TURN service, it does not play any active part in communication after latter is established.

WebRTC is a bit complex, especially if you are expecting an API along the lines of `send` and `receive`, but a simplified connection example should be understandable to a developer.

You may also not need to use WebRTC API directly, there are libraries that encapsulate WebRTC into a simpler API of one flavour or another, API that simultaneously hides the more fringe or "boilerplate" aspects of WebRTC and which also helps minimize the risk of getting into trouble as different user agents are notorious for implementing different parts of WebRTC a bit differently.

One of these libraries is [PeerJS](https://github.com/peers/peerjs/) but there are others, without a doubt.

The WebSocket API, unlike WebRTC, requires a WebSocket compliant server, and WebSocket API does not do peer-to-peer. The good news is that 1) a WebSocket compliant service is typically just an advanced relay (often fused with an application back-end logic), albeit working on the application level instead of the session level for TURN and 2) there are plenty of "turn-key" WebSocket server implementations out there.

Comment: WebRTC needs an application backend, the signaling server. It has the function you attribute to the STUN servers (whose job is to tell the client its public ip).
Many of those signaling servers are written in nodejs.

Comment: You are right, although I'd argue that a signaling server is not an application backend (as the former can be generic and know next to nothing about the application).

Comment: WebRTC for such a use case will be an overkill and makes no real sense. A better approach would be to use "a" server to negotiate the messages across players. Be it Node.js, Java, Go, Python or assembly based is almost irrelevant.
I'd go with something like PubNub, Pusher, Scaledrone or even Firebase if there's no desire to manage and maintain the backend for it.

Comment: The question was edited to include the critical information that it's a Tic-Tac-Toe game, after I wrote the answer and the latter accepted before I saw the edit and by then it was too late -- accepted answers cannot be deleted. As to using WebRTC for Tic-Tac-Toe, yes that'd be a bit unnecessary I suppose, although I don't see the harm learning how accomplish RTC between Web browsers.